# Nil object using generic fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, fields-for

I am trying to pass parameters using a generic fields_for method. I have a form:

```
<%= form_for @Album do |album| %>
...
<%= fields_for :photo do |photo| %>
  <%= photo.text_field :name %>
  <%= photo.text_area  :description %>
  ...
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

I was hoping this form would generate photo[name] and photo[description] so that when I submit the form, my controller can do a check if params[:photo] exists... #do something.
The reason I am not using nested forms, is because sometimes these form fields won't even be used.

The issue is that I am getting is an error for the fields_for :photo line. It says you have a nil object when you didnt expect it! You might have expected an instance of an array.

How can I do this generic fields_for without it being nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're encountering this problem because there's no @photo variable defined in your controller. `fields_for`, just like `form_for`, is intended to be a wrapper for an existing object. The symbol `:photo` is being turned into an instance variable, but it's nil and so that's why you're hitting these errors. You can correct this by defining the photo in the controller action:

```
@photo = @album.photos.first # if there's an existing photo
@photo = @album.photos.new # if there's not
```

If you don't want to define an object at all, then you'll need to just use the regular form tags instead of `fields_for`.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably go ahead and use regular form tags, I gave somewhat of a bad example using an album and photo model with what I am trying to do. But this definitely clears things up, thank you so much!